# How can I create a custom Locale

Tags: java, datetime, locale

Using Java 8 DateTime functions, I find that the NARROW names for certain days of the week are not what I'd like. I want "R" for Thursday, "S" for Saturday, and "U" for Sunday. Naturally I can create a HashMap, ArrayList, or Array to do the conversion, but what I'd really like is to create a Locale of my own where the formatting (DayOfWeek#getDisplayName()) does what I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) is a final class which does not implement any interfaces (well, besides `Serializable` and `Cloneable`), so no you can't. I don't see anything wrong with creating a map, as you suggested you'd already considered.

Comment: The easiest way to do something like this is to create an enum called DayOfWeek with each of the days in it. You can then create a getDisplayName() method in the enum.

Comment: What I'm driving at is that I'd like to create a locale of my own. There is "en_US" for example, how can I create "en_GREG"?